# Jinja2 - Render list items in groups of x

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am looking to output a list of items in a table in a jinja2 template.

current code:

```
<table style="width:100%">
{% for i in sales %}
  <tr>
     <td>{{i}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Which results in:

```
item
item
item
item
...
```

Expected output:

```
item    item    item        
item    item    item    
item    item    item    
item    item    item    
...
```

I would like the output to be spread over three columns, ie. loop from left to right in the table and then start a new row after 3 items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [batch](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.batch)

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> t = jinja2.Template("{% for i in items|batch(3) %}{{i}}{% endfor %}")
>>> items = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
>>> print t.render(items=items)
>>> ['1', '2', '3']['4', '5', '6']['7', '8', '9']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`divisibleby`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#divisibleby) test.

```
{% for i in sales %}
  {% if loop.index0 is divisibleby(3) %}
  <tr>
  {% endif %}
     <td>{{i}}</td>
  {% if loop.index is divisibleby(3) %}
  </tr>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this jsut outputs a row: `item item item ... item`